# What should pilots state initially when telephoning a weather briefing facility for preflight weather information?

Tags: faa-regulations, weather, aim, fss

I've gotten this question wrong multiple times on practice tests. Sporty's study buddy claims the information is sourced from AIM 7-1, but it's nowhere to be found.

Correct answers included:

- The intended route of flight and destination
- Tail number
- Identify themselves as pilots

What is the actual authoritative language that covers this test question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in [the AIM](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim.pdf) 5-1-1(f):

> When requesting a preflight briefing, identify yourself as a pilot and
> provide the following:
>
> 1. Type of flight planned; e.g., VFR or IFR.
> 2. Aircraft’s number or pilot’s name.
> 3. Aircraft type.
> 4. Departure Airport.
> 5. Route of flight.
> 6. Destination.
> 7. Flight altitude(s).
> 8. ETD and ETE

Personally, I've never given or been asked for the aircraft type (although I have it on my [LMFS](https://www.1800wxbrief.com) profile so they should have it), but the other items come up. My typical request is something like this:

> This is N12345, I'd like a standard briefing for a VFR flight from
> KMDQ to KLOU at 5500', ETD at 1600Z, ETE 2h15

Comment: Note that these are many of the same fields as a in flight plan

Comment: @rbp yes, many of the red herring answers confuse flight plan fields with the 'initial ID'. I even answered 'state their total flight time' which is ETE and got it marked wrong in favor of Identifying as a pilot. The only logic I can see to answering this question is to use 5-1-1(f) ranked by order of importance when multiple options exist.

Comment: remember that when you file a flight plan, you will get a standard briefing in return.